# iPhone Emoji Unicode Encoding UTF

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, encode, emoji

I'm encoding Unicode Emoji characters into a string and loading that into a webview..

for the encoding I'm using "NSUTF8StringEncoding" But the emoji characters just show up as jiberish unicode symbols like ∆¬ÓÔÓ˝ˆ So what encoding do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSUTF32StringEncoding` did the trick, didn't see it on the list of encoding before.

Comment: Great that you worked it out Albert! :) Certainly, do leave the question on here, but I suggest marking it as answered (by yourself), as otherwise it will keep showing up on unanswered question lists for others. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks :) I tried but it says I have to wait 2 days before accepting my own answer... Is there a setting on the question I can change to have it not show up on the open questions part of the website?

Comment: Hmmm.. Not that I know of (a bit new here myself :)). But I'm sure that will be fine.