# Displaying Emojis from Twitter api?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, emoji

I have an app that retrieves a user's stream and puts it into a UITableView. However, some include emojis (those little smile faces in iOS), and they just return as boxes in my UILabel.

I've done some research, and I still can't figure it out. Does the text type need to be changed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please explain your problem better,from the piece that i understood,notice that emojis have native support in iPhone,so any app can display an emoji in a text box,i recommend you to check the methods you're using to add text to the uitableview and the **text encoding** from the string which is being displayed,also you could check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357006/iphone-emoji-unicode-encoding-utf)

Answer (score 0):

use NSString drawinrect to display emoji instead of drawGlyphsForGlyphRange.